# DataTable to JSON to Controller to jqGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have 3 forms, `Associate.cs, HomeController.cs, Index.cshtml.`

I load a `DataTable` from `Associate.cs` and use this code to get it into JSON format.

```
    public string GetAssociateFromDB()
       //code omitted
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
                jsonData = json;
            }               
        }
        return jsonData; //return is good
```

I call this from `HomeController.cs`.

```
    public JsonResult GetJsonData()
    {
        Associate associate = new Associate();
        string jsonData = associate.GetAssociateFromDB();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonData); //for testing purposes
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  //need to pass to `Index.cshtml`
    }
```

However, this code doesn't get hit unless I put the method in this block:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GetJsonData(); //if not called here, it never gets hit.

        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
```

Then, I try to pass it to Index.cshtml, via `$.getJSON` method, but it never reaches it.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var mydata;
     $.getJSON('@Url.Action("HomeController", "GetJsonData")', function(data) {
         datatype: 'json'
         mydata = data;
         console.log(data); //unsure if this works or not.
     });
```

I am then trying to supply that data for a `jqGrid` (this is just under the above code):

```
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "json",
    width: '100%',
    colNames: ["Seq ID", "Fund ID", "Name", "Fund", "Bonus", "Allocation", "Blank", "Begin", "End"],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'seqid',
        index: 'seqid',
        editable: true,
    },....//Code omitted
```

I can't seem to get the data from the `Controller` to `Index.cshtml`.
I have read on a blog that there is a problem with `cache` in IE 8, which is what I am testing in, but I'm pretty sure that's not my initial problem.

I've read the jQGrid documentation and searched many times, but the only example is for this kind of thing is for PHP or in a different context. I tried putting `[HttpGet]` above the `GetJsonData` method, and that did not work either.

It's also important to note I haven't written much(any) jQuery before.

Comment: @Url.Action("HomeController", "GetJsonData")' is it correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't get the code to hit it.

Comment: this will not hit.because arugment is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code.

```
Url.Action('actionname','controllername')
```

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var mydata;
         $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Home")', function(data) {
             datatype: 'json'
             mydata = data;
             gridFn(data);
         });

function gridFn(data)
{
//here grid code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The `alert(data)` was populated correctly. Do you know about passing `data` from the above method to `$("#grid").jqGrid(` ?

Comment: It doesn't like that. I did exactly what you said. `function gridFn(data) {  //grid code }`

Comment: @MurDer i cant get you what you meant exactly?

Comment: So, in `$.getJSON()` we have `data`. When I tried to pass that value to `$("#grid").jqGrid({ }` I receive an error "p.colModel" is null or not an object.. Do you want me to paste my `jqGrid` code?